# Ideas on making a Java Application with Nutch/Elastic Search and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nutch

I have an idea for an application make a search engine using tools Nutch, ES and Kibana. Nutch for crawling, ES for indexing and Kibana for the visualisation.

Currently, I have all the programs fine and I can successfully use them in terminal. My question is, is it possible to make a Java Application which incoporates Nutch, Es and Kibana all in one?

My idea for the application is that it will accept a URL for nutch to crawl, after crawling it will then accept terms to index. Finally, it will make a visualisation page with Kibana of the data.

Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Using Nutch to crawl URLs one by one is an overkill and would be very inefficient. You'd be better off putting these URLs in a queue and get e.g. StormCrawler to pull from the queue and process these URLs on the fly then index them to ES.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have them as a single application? ES and Kibana are services and meant to run continuously. If you had StormCrawler (see comment above) that would be another continuous service. All you'd need to do is build a UI to send the URLs to a queue.

Comment: Does StormCrawler have the ability to make certain modifications to documents? For modifying the ability if the documents are stemmed or not?

Comment: yes it can extract or modify the documents before sending to ES. The stemming typically occurs within ES though.

Comment: Hello Julien, can you please take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281244/stormcrawler-cannot-connect-to-elasticsearch