# StormCrawler cannot connect to ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

While running the command:

```
storm jar target/crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --local es-injector.flux --sleep 86400000
```

I get an error saying:

```
8710 [Thread-26-status-executor[4 4]] ERROR c.d.s.e.p.StatusUpdaterBolt - 
Can't connect to ElasticSearch
```

When running http://localhost:9200/ in browser ES successfully loads up. Kibana also connects to ES. So it must just be the connection from StromCrawler to ElasticSearch.

What could be the issue?

Snippet of full error:

```
8710 [Thread-26-status-executor[4 4]] ERROR c.d.s.e.p.StatusUpdaterBolt - Can't connect to ElasticSearch
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: http: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getClient(ElasticSearchConnection.java:107) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getConnection(ElasticSearchConnection.java:151) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt.prepare(StatusUpdaterBolt.java:141) [crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$fn__5057.invoke(executor.clj:791) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getClient(ElasticSearchConnection.java:104) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 6 more
8710 [Thread-18-__metricscom.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.MetricsConsumer-executor[2 2]] ERROR c.d.s.e.m.MetricsConsumer - Can't connect to ElasticSearch
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: http
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getClient(ElasticSearchConnection.java:107) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getConnection(ElasticSearchConnection.java:151) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getConnection(ElasticSearchConnection.java:133) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.MetricsConsumer.prepare(MetricsConsumer.java:68) [crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.metric.MetricsConsumerBolt.prepare(MetricsConsumerBolt.java:77) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$fn__5057.invoke(executor.clj:791) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getClient(ElasticSearchConnection.java:104) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 8 more
8714 [Thread-26-status-executor[4 4]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: http: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt.prepare(StatusUpdaterBolt.java:145) ~[crawlIndexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$fn__5057.invoke(executor.clj:791) ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
```

Perhaps there is something I need to modify in elasticsearch.yml or es-conf.yml? (They both have default settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the application to work by playing around (for many hours).

Steps:

- Reverted back Storm-Crawler-Core and Storm-Crawler-Elastic-Search to version 1.5 in the maven file.
- Used the 1.5 flux/yaml config file versions from Storm-Crawler-Elastic-Search
- Using Elastic Search 5.4.0
- Using Kibana 5.4.0

Comment: I am using SC + ES (6.0.1) for large scale crawls in version 1.7 without any issues on Storm 1.1.1 - maybe you can uodate your question with the appropriate conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message above mentions ElasticSearchConnection.java:104 so you must be using a release and not the code from the master branch. Make sure the es conf corresponds to the [same version](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.7/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml). Did you copy the conf from the master branch? The next release will have a different format for the addresses

Comment: I triple checked everything and I was using the latest version of everything. However it's fine, I will just use the older versions are they seem to work well.

Comment: ) When running the crawl command multiple times " org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --local es-crawler.flux" does StormCrawler get crawl new sites every time or does it crawl the same web pages?

Comment: it's meant to run continuously (use the sleep parameter in local mode as per the README) - there is no point calling it several times. As for the rest of your question, see WIKI and tutorials. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. When I run the crawler, it does successfully crawl websites and output to ES but it either ends with an exception (to do with Storm I think) or stops executing and just says 'All connections are ready for worker '. I assume this is not normal? Is it supposed to just keep crawling indefinitely?

Comment: @Julien Nioche when will be version 1.8? I have something same error I need work with ES6.x. I wait next version SC.

Comment: @IvanBukharin feel free to use the master branch from GIT and report on any success (or problems), that would help getting the release sooner.